# How to hide other users processes from 'ps aux' output for 'users' group? Debian squeeze

Tags: linux, security, unix, debian

I'm running Debian. I want users to be unable to see my processes when they type 'ps aux'. A web search wasn't clear enough on how to do that, but it seems to be possible. How do I do that?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this question on the [Unix/Linux Stackexchange site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), for help with Unix/Linux, as opposed to programming.

Comment: Hardened kernel can provide this, but are they worth the effort ?

Comment: This has been deliberately made harder in newer kernels, as this is how rootkits like to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no simple ways, other than fancy things like tweaking the kernel code or the ps command code, or things like trying to use an innocent-looking name for the process. See:

https://superuser.com/questions/199044/is-it-possible-to-hide-a-process-from-the-listing-of-ps-or-top-on-linux

There are no questions of users or groups: everyone can see everyone's processes.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. What are your motivations for doing this?

Comment: Understandable, but why would this cause you or your users problems?  Have you considered giving users no access to /bin/ps or /proc and not permitting them to write executable files (noexec mount)?

Comment: Actually, it is possible: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11873/2644 http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1326/2644 http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17164/2644